# Set windows/ad account to support encryption algorithm AES 128/256 in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, aes

I want to set an Active directory account that will support the AES 128 and 256 encryption algorithm in C# code
Just check these fields:
[image]

I am using System.DirectoryServices.dll for AD operation.
To update another "never expire" setting for example I use this code:

```
int NON_EXPIRE_FLAG = 0x10000;
val = (int) NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | NON_EXPIRE_FLAG;
NewUser.CommitChanges();
```

Can you tell me how can I set Encryption algorithm AES 128 and 256 ?

I tried to google a lot
I only found a way via power shell
https://serverfault.com/questions/616487/why-dont-active-directory-user-accounts-automatically-support-kerberos-aes-auth
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/security/configuration-to-support-kerberos-aes-encryption

I tried to convert to C# - but I get this exception: "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.\r\n"

Comment: Take an account, uncheck both options, then **GET** the property values and record them. Then check the boxes for the account, GET the values again, and see what changed. Then you will know what to set.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to try and set the `msDs-supportedEncryptionTypes` attribute?

Comment: Note that ServerFault answer you linked to has a typo in the PowerShell code where it missed the "s" at the end of the attribute name in one place.

Comment: @Coehoorn - Can you elaborate on how AD commands can be recorded (I'm local to the machine, it doesn't go over the network)?

Comment: Thanks Luci,  I'm using  "msDs-supportedEncryptionTypes" with these values
AES256 encryption = 0x10, AES128encryption = 0x08.
And it worked for me
Code:
        private const int AES256encryption = 0x10;
        private const int AES128encryption = 0x08;
        private void SetAccountToSupportAESEncryption(DirectoryEntry user, bool aes128=true, bool aes256=true)
        {        
            user.Properties["msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes"].Value = 0x10 ((aes256)?AES256encryption:0)|((aes128) ? AES128encryption:0);
            user.CommitChanges();            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luci for your comment,  I'm using  "msDs-supportedEncryptionTypes" with these values
AES256 encryption = 0x10, AES128encryption = 0x08.
And it worked for me

Code:
[image: Set AC account encryption to AES]

Regarding these parameters - they always return NULL to me and I can't put a value in them (CommitChanges() failed) - but I don't need them that much anymore :)
user.Properties["Account Supports AES256 bit encryption"].Value
user.Properties["Account Supports AES128 bit encryption"].Value